# How many permutations if three items are selected with repeats from {a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c}?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I tried to solve this question by using the following formula for permutation with repeating values (source: https://www.ck12.org/probability/permutations-with-repetition/lesson/Permutations-with-Repetition-BSC-PST/ ):
$$
    \frac{{n}P{k}}{x_1!x_2!x_3!}
 $$
Since there are 3 letters each repeating 3 times in the set, and we’re selecting 3 letters out of the set of 9 letters, I ended up with the following result:

$$
\frac{9!}{(9-3)!3!3!3!}=\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7}{3!3!3!}=\frac{504}{216}=2.333
$$

I’m pretty sure $2.333$ isn’t the right answer, considering how ABC, AAA, BBB, CCC already form four permutations, and I don’t think there can be $2.33$ permutations.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The cited formula is incorrect, and your specific example is a great counterexample.  The answer to every counting problem *must* be a whole number... so getting a fractional number is of course going to be incorrect.  As for what is wrong?  The *explanation* of *why* they thought that formula was correct might have something to do with "dividing by symmetry"... If we were arranging all nine of the letters and treat all letters as distinct, then we recognize that we overcounted because for each of the $3!$ rearrangements of the $A$'s we intended to treat them as the same...

Comment: Same for the other letters.  *However*... with $9\times 8\times 7$... only arranging three of the letters... we *aren't* overcounting to the same extent as if we were arranging all nine of them.  Several of the letters swapping positions that might have occurred in the problem had we arranged all nine don't result in accidentally considered different outcomes here.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to choose each of three letters. Therefore the total number of "permutations" is
$$3^3=27.$$

UPDATE:

In general the number of ordered $k$-subsets of a multiset containing $n_i$ elements of type $i$ ($i=1\dots M$) is the coefficient at $x^k$ of the polynomial:
$$
k! \prod_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=0}^{n_i}\frac{x^j}{j!}\tag1
$$

In your example it is:
$$
\left[3!\left(1+\frac x{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\right)^3\right]_3=27.
$$

Comment: Is there a way of solving this if the set was slightly different and there are different number of repetition for each letter, for example if the set was {a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c}?

Comment: If you have more letters at stock than you need (b), the exact number does not matter. If you have less than you need (a)  it should be accounted for. In your new example the sequence 'aaa' is impossible. Therefore the answer is 26.

Comment: I have added a general formula for arbitrary number of repititions for each letter.